# Black square when viewing LaTeX

Tags: bug, android-app

For a while, I have had this problem that whenever I am trying to view a question on math stackexchange that involves LaTeX, after a second or two the whole text gets covered in black like this:

[image: Black Bar]

The app has worked on my phone before, and it still works on non LaTeX questions, but this bug persisted through the last updates I did.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: Mi 4i
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (7.11.6)